How can I extract Outlook message, dragged via OLE drag-and-drop to my window?
My program (C++, Windows) implements a window, receiving OLE drag-and-drop object (a message dragged from MS Outlook), enumerates formats of dragged objects, reads a stream when TYMED_ISTREAM is received.
But I am confused - how can I extract an Outlook letter and it's components (letter body, attachments, attributes - From:, To:, Subject etc.)
The attached screenshot shows a listing - what I have read, enumerated FORMATETC records (it's main fields are shown).
For example, I have read 302 bytes from a stream, format code = 49814.
Question1:
But how can I extract Outlook letter from these 302 bytes ?
Could you please tell me the plan of my actions to do that ?
Question2:
Should I or not to call RegisterClipboardormat (I did not) ?
If yes, (2.1) which code should I register and (2.2) why should this be done (why my enumeration is not enough)  ?
Additionally, I have got system name of several format codes (via GetClipboardFormatName):
49968 - RenPrivateLatestMessages,
49735 - RenPrivateMessages,
49708 - RenPrivateItem,
49395 - FileGroupDescriptor,
49159 - FileNameW
etc.
Which of them are usefull and allow to get Outlook message ?
The code, used to enumerate dropped objects/formats:
HRESULT __stdcall MyDropTarget_CLASS::Drop(IDataObject* pDataObj, DWORD grfKeyState,
    POINTL pt,
    DWORD* pdwEffect) {

    bool ok_get_enum = false, ok_reset = false;

    DragWindowPtr->SetNormalBrush();

    IEnumFORMATETC* ppenumFormatEtc;
    HRESULT res = pDataObj->EnumFormatEtc(DATADIR_GET, &ppenumFormatEtc);
    ok_get_enum = (res == S_OK);
    if (!ok_get_enum)
        std::cout << "EnumFormatEtc ERROR = " << res << std::endl;

    if (ok_get_enum) {
        res = ppenumFormatEtc->Reset();
        ok_reset = (res == S_OK);
        if (!ok_reset)
            std::cout << "EnumFormatEtc.Reset ERROR = " << res << std::endl;
    }

    if (ok_reset) {

        std::cout << "------ Enumerating ---------" << std::endl;

        const ULONG ElementsInPortions = 5;     // сколько записей читаем
        FORMATETC ItemsArray[ElementsInPortions];
        ULONG FetchedNumber = 0;
        bool DoNext = true;
        while (DoNext) {
            DoNext = (res = ppenumFormatEtc->Next(ElementsInPortions, &(ItemsArray[0]), &FetchedNumber)) == S_OK;
            std::cout << "Requested = " << ElementsInPortions << "    Fetched = " << FetchedNumber << std::endl;
            for (ULONG i = 0; i < FetchedNumber; i++) {

                CLIPFORMAT CurFormatCode = ItemsArray[i].cfFormat;
                DWORD CurAspect = ItemsArray[i].dwAspect;
                DWORD CurTymed = ItemsArray[i].tymed;
                LONG LIndex = ItemsArray[i].lindex;

                std::cout << "      Format = " << CurFormatCode << "(" << GetFormatName(CurFormatCode) << ")" <<
                    "   Aspect = " << CurAspect <<
                    "   Tymed = " << CurTymed << "(" << GetTymedName(CurTymed) << ")" <<
                    "   LIndex = " << LIndex << std::endl;




                if (CurTymed == TYMED_ISTREAM) {
                    std::cout << "--------- Reading from a stream ---------" << std::endl;
                    GetData_IStream(pDataObj, &(ItemsArray[i]));
                    std::cout << "-----------------------------------------" << std::endl << std::endl;
                }

            }

        }

        std::cout << "------ FINISHED ---------" << std::endl;

        ppenumFormatEtc->Release();
    }

    *pdwEffect = DROPEFFECT_COPY;

    return S_OK;
}

// The code that reads ISTREAM

bool GetData_IStream(IDataObject* pDataObj, const FORMATETC* in_FormatEtc) {


    // ---------------- QueryGetData ----------------

    FORMATETC ReadFormat;
    ZeroMemory(&ReadFormat, sizeof(ReadFormat));

    ReadFormat.cfFormat = in_FormatEtc->cfFormat;                     // CLIPFORMAT
    ReadFormat.tymed = TYMED_ISTREAM;           // DWORD
    ReadFormat.ptd = NULL;                      //  [unique] DVTARGETDEVICE*
    ReadFormat.dwAspect = DVASPECT_CONTENT;     // DWORD
    ReadFormat.lindex = -1;                     // LONG

    HRESULT res = pDataObj->QueryGetData(&ReadFormat);
    bool ok_query = (res == S_OK);
    if (ok_query)
        std::cout << "QueryGetData - OK" << std::endl;
    else {
        std::cout << "QueryGetData - ERROR = " << res << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    

    // ---------------- GetData ----------------

    ZeroMemory(&ReadFormat, sizeof(ReadFormat));

    ReadFormat.cfFormat = in_FormatEtc->cfFormat;                     // CLIPFORMAT
    ReadFormat.tymed = TYMED_ISTREAM;           // DWORD
    ReadFormat.ptd = NULL;                      //  [unique] DVTARGETDEVICE*
    ReadFormat.dwAspect = DVASPECT_CONTENT;     // DWORD
    ReadFormat.lindex = -1;                     // LONG

    STGMEDIUM MediumInfo;   
    res = pDataObj->GetData(&ReadFormat, &MediumInfo);
    bool ok_getdata = (res == S_OK);
    if (ok_getdata)
        std::cout << "GetData - OK" << std::endl;
    else {
        std::cout << "GetData - ERROR = " << res << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // MediumInfo должен содержать актуальную ссылку на IStream
    if (MediumInfo.tymed != ReadFormat.tymed) {
        std::cout << "GetData ERROR - invalid _MediumInfo.tymed_ = " << MediumInfo.tymed << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    IStream* Stream = MediumInfo.pstm;
    if (Stream == NULL) {
        std::cout << "GetData ERROR - Stream == NULL." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    bool ReadResult = false;

    // ---------------- allocate a buffer to read stream ----------------
    const int BufferSize = 100000;
    char* BufferPtr = (char* ) malloc(BufferSize);
    if (BufferPtr != nullptr) {

        // ---------------- Read the Stream ------------------------
        ULONG ActuallyRead = 0;     
        ULONG TotalRead = 0;        
        bool StreamEof = false;
        bool ReadError = false;

        // --- позицинируем в начало ---
        ULARGE_INTEGER NewPos = { 0, 0 };
        LARGE_INTEGER SetPos = { 0, 0 };
        HRESULT res_seek = Stream->Seek(SetPos, STREAM_SEEK_SET, &NewPos);
        ReadError = (res_seek != S_OK);

        if (ReadError) {
            bool pending = res_seek == E_PENDING;
            if (pending)
                std::cout << "Stream.Seek is pending :((" << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "Stream.Seek ERROR = " << res_seek << std::endl;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Stream.Seek OK. New pos = LO=" << NewPos.LowPart << "  HI=" << NewPos.HighPart << std::endl;

        while (!StreamEof && !ReadError) {
            HRESULT res_read = Stream->Read(BufferPtr, (ULONG) BufferSize, &ActuallyRead);

            switch (res_read) {
                case S_OK: 
                case S_FALSE: {
                    // --- we have read something ---

                    StreamEof = (ActuallyRead < BufferSize);
                    TotalRead = TotalRead + ActuallyRead;

                    break;
                }  // S_OK, S_FALSE

                case E_PENDING: {
                    // pending... - not processed
                    break;
                } // E_PENDING

                default: {
                    
                    ReadError = true;
                    std::cout << "Stream reading ERROR = " <<res_read << std::endl;

                } // default
            } // switch


        } // while

        ReadResult = !ReadError;

        if (!ReadError) {
            std::cout << "Stream reading OK. TotalRead = " << TotalRead << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Malloc ERROR - cannot alloc memory for a stream data." << std::endl;
        ReadResult = false;
    }


    Stream->Release();

    return ReadResult;
}


The stream you get is really an MSG file (which is an IStorage file). You can either

open the message as an Extended MAPI IMessage object using StgOpenStorage/OpenIMsgOnIStg,
use Outlook Object Model (NameSpace.OpenSharedItem)
Parse the IStorage object opened using StgOpenStorage


,@Dmitry Streblechenko, thank you for your reply! Could not you explain me about StgOpenStorage (I am new in OLE drag-and-drop and Outlook interaction):
description in MSDN says - it opens an existing root storage object.
StgOpenStorage gets as input either const WCHAR *pwcsName (UNICODE string) or IStorage *pstgPriority. How can I apply it to my IStream data ?

Dmitry, do you mean I should use the tymed==TYMED_ISTORAGE  ? What is in the tymed==TYMED_ISTREAM then (in the stream) ? I doubt the MSG file in the stream, because the stream size = 302 bytes, but the MSG file is about 19K bytes.

You can either save the stream as file and use StgOpenStorage or implement a class that exposes the ILockBytes interface and use StgOpenStorageOnILockBytes

Which clipboard format are you looking at? Is it CF_FILECONTENTS? Then its content will indeed be TYMED_ISTREAM

Dmitry, I am looking any format that will give me access to  a MSG file, that represents a letter being dragged. By the way, Are the formats RenPrivateLatestMessages, RenPrivateMessages, RenPrivateItem are applicable for me to get MSG file ?
Their sizes are too small to be a MSG file (about 19K)...

Dmitry, I have read CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR format (HGLOBAL) with 1 record with file name = "subject.msg".
Then I have read CFSTR_FILECONTENTS with tymed = 12 (ISTREAM || ISTORAGE), the GetData() returned a storage.
I have enumerated the storage (Reset/Next) and got about 18! records in the storage. 16 names of them like "substg1.0_001A001F" etc (STGTY type 2 = stream), several (2) of type = 1 (storage).
The saved MSG from Outlook (19K). But the mentioned records contains less bytes. Q.: Is this storage is applicable and is the right way ? And how can I get MSG file from them ?

Dmitry, regarding your comment "Which clipboard format are you looking at? Is it CF_FILECONTENTS? Then its content will indeed be TYMED_ISTREAM".
If I call GetData() with format f=RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILECONTENTS) and medium type = TYMED_ISTREAM, then GetData() returns an error E_INVALIDARGS.
If I call GetData() with medium type = TYMED_ISTREAM | TYMED_ISTORAGE (12), then it returns TYMED_ISTORAGE.
So I can work with FILECONTENTS with IStorage only ? You have said about IStream. Why GetData() does not return IStream` so ?

"substg1.0_001A001F" is what you get for a MAPI property. 0x001A001F is PR_MESSAGE_CLASS_W - you are accessing the raw MSG file's contents. The IStorage parts are attachments and recipients.

Dmitry, you answers is very informative for me! If I'd like to save the storage mentioned above (with 18 entries inside), will be a saved file - a MSG file (can Outlook open it as a MSG) ? Or I should save it to get a MSG file in another way (as I have mentioned above I can't get IStream with a MSG directly) ?

If you already have IStorage, you might as well save it as an MSG file.

Dmitry, Thank you very much!
